# Python: Pandas: Merging Two dataframes - no values in right columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I cannot show my dataframes unfortunately, but I think this is a fairly simple join, so it should be okay (hopefully).

Sample of dataframe as per request:

```
Machine Serial  Shift Number    IP Number   Previous IP number Processing End Time
123             1600            34          33                 2022-17-05 08:00:00
123             1600            35          34                 2022-17-05 08:01:00
F35             1302            700         699                2022-15-05 09:23:00
F35             1302            701         700                2022-15-05 09:23:45
```

I have a dataframe that I am joining to itself In order to get the processing end time of the previous IP (aka the IP's start time). I have created two join fields that are concatenated from 3 columns each.

```
query_result['Left Join Key'] = query_result['Machine Serial'].astype(str) + query_result['Shift Number'].astype(str) + query_result['Previous IP Number'].astype(str)

query_result['Right Join Key'] = query_result['Machine Serial'].astype(str) + query_result['Shift Number'].astype(str) + query_result['IP Number'].astype(str)
```

Here are the datatypes of all four columns involved in those calculations:

```
Machine Serial           object
Shift Number              int64
IP Number                 int64
Previous IP Number      float64
```

Here are the datatypes of the resulting columns:

```
Left Join Key            object
Right Join Key           object
```

Then, I join the dataframe to itself with this code:

```
joined_query_result = query_result.merge(query_result, how='left', left_on = 'Left Join Key', right_on= 'Right Join Key', suffixes=('.IP', '.PreviousIP'))
```

The columns from the right handed dataframe are blank, and it seems to not be joining properly. I know for a fact that there are values in 'Left Join Key' that should match up just fine to values in 'Right Join Key'.

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I am willing to hear other ideas of how to accomplish this. I am not so experienced with Pandas.

**Update: at the suggestion of Paul H (in the comments below) I passed the fields directly into the merge instead of creating a concatenated column. This caused the join to function properly.**

Comment: Could you create an example of the two dataframes with dummy data? That would help answer your question

Comment: You can pass multiple columns to the merge command. No need to smush all that data together

Comment: Your join keys need to be identical.  if you have two different keys (e.g., `['Machine Serial'] + ['Shift Number'] + ['IP Number']` and `['Machine Serial'] + ['Shift Number'] + [Previous IP nmber']`), you should expect the merge to return a blank column.

Comment: @dubbbdan not necessarily. What matters is that the column values match. The names of the columns are irrelevant

Comment: @PaulH right, but looking at the example:   Since `IP Number` never matches `Previous IP number`, there would be nothing to merge.  This isn't really a merge, as I understand it. OP wants to compare values on the same row.  Seems more like a `.loc` application, than a `merge`

Comment: also, `pd.merge` defaults in an inner merge.  I also think OP is interested in a left merge.

Comment: @dubbbdan I am interested in what you mean about using .loc over merge. Let me add a column to the sample dataframe and explain to you what I am trying to do.

Comment: @dubbbdan, of course. But that's a data issue and has nothing to do with the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given in the comments, and I am bumping it because it solved the issue (though, I am not sure why):

You can pass multiple columns to the merge command. No need to smush all that data together –
Paul H

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).